# Can't use basic kotlin function like "until" in a for-loop or for each

Tags: android, kotlin

So to not repeat my initial question that might give some background I'll just attach a [link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095931/how-do-i-access-the-chipgroup-content-so-i-could-save-it)

So I currently need to iterate through a ChipGroup, and when I try to introduce "for each" or "until", android studio gives me an unresolved reference notice.
I've checked and double checked and I don't think I am writing it in a bad way, but the studio doesn't let me use it for some reason.
The rest of my code which is entirely kotlin is completely fine.

```
    questionButton.setOnClickListener {

        questionChipGroup.forEach

        for ( i in questionChipGroup until questionChipGroup.childCount){


        }


        postQuestion(
            questionTitle.text.toString(),
            questionDetails.text.toString(),
            questionTags.text.toString(),
            System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
        )

    }
```

[image]

In the examples above, both `until` and `forEach` are red and are basically unrecognized by Android.

I tried to invalidate the cache and restart and that didn't help.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What's that `forEach` above your `for` loop?

Comment: You can't use until here. If your questionChipGroup is already iterable

Comment: what's the type of `questionChipGroup`?

Comment: @HamedMomeni the forEach was just an effort but Android didn't allow me to use it which is part of the reason I've posted the question.

Comment: @ArtemBotnev I found it as a solution for the notice I got from Android when trying to use a simple `for (i in questionChipGroup)`. The notice I got was `for loop range must have an iterator() method`. If that's not a solution as it is obviously not acceptable, do you know what the solution for my problem would be?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 it is a ChipGroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [ChipGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup) API in android. It is basically a sub-type of `ViewGroup`, so  to iterate through a `ChipGroup`.

```
for ( index in 0 until questionChipGroup.childCount){
    val childView = questionChipGroup.getChildAt(index)

    // Process childView here
}
```

[forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) in Kotlin only works on [Iterator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterator/index.html). Because `ChipGroup` does not implement `Iterator` interface, that why you cannot use `forEach` on it.

[until](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) in Kotlin is not an infix function, but also an extension function. It only works on `Byte, Short, Int, Long` type, that why you cannot call it from `questionChipGroup` (its type is `ChipGroup`).

Comment: I'll ditch the forEach effort, but I am unable to use until either. Android is giving me an error saying unresolved reference. I'll upload a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. Still I am updating my answer so it may help somebody.
Check if your project supports Kotlin. Also, your Android Studio Kotlin plugin and the Kotlin runtime/compiler that you use in the project should match.

Update the IDE Kotlin plugin version to match the project by doing this: Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates -> Check for updates now

Check [this](https://tedblob.com/kotlin-loop-until/) to know various ways to use until